# Get property Null Reference Exception

Tags: c#-3.0

I am sending `CurrentPage` value 1, but it gives a null reference exception in `set`.

`lblCurrentPage` is a label control. `CurrentPage` is one variable.

```
public int CurrentPage
{

    get { return int.Parse(lblCurrentPage.Text); }
    set {
             lblCurrentPage.Text = Convert.ToString(value);
        }
}
```

Comment: Stacktrace or where exactly is the null...post more info please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a massive lack of info for us to go on, but i'll make a suggestion. Check that lblCurrentPage is actually set to a real control, i.e. make sure the label has been instantiated before you try to set its properties.

```
public int CurrentPage 
{
    get 
    { 
        int temp = 0;
        if (lblCurrentPage != null) 
        {
            int.TryParse(lblCurrentPage.Text, out temp);
        }
        return temp;
    }
    set 
    {
        if (lblCurrentPage != null)
            lblCurrentPage.Text = Convert.ToString(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You very much. I am preparing Paging user control for gridview. If you any suggestions send me.